# Chronoform mail not showing field values

Tags: joomla2.5

I    have    a    site which is joomla 2.5 version. I have used chronoform. I have configured chronoform mail with field values like Nombre{Nombre}.But the mail is going in spam and in the body I am getting like below..

```
Nombre    {Nombre}
Apellido    {Apellido}
Ciudad    {Ciudad}
Telefono    {Telefono}
Correo electrónico    {Correo electronico}
Mensaje    {Mensaje}

I     am    not    getting the values of {Nombre} etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the field name is declared in chronoforms.
If you go into your form and click on the wizard (if you used the wizard) - you'll see your form fields.  Click to edit your form field and your options window will appear.

You will see 'Label Text', 'Field Name', 'Field Default Value', etc.

You MUST fill in the field name for each of them in order to get their values into the email.  So for example Nombre would be:

Label Text: Nombre:

Field Name: Nombre

Then you could do "Nombre: {Nombre}" in your email template to get the value.